# All files access permission: Need to use MediaStore API

Tags: android

Issue: Need to use Media Store API or No Access to Files

You have requested access to All Files Access permission but it appears that your app's core feature requires access to only Media Files or does not need access to any Files. In case your app needs access to Media Files, with the MediaStore API, apps can contribute and access media that's available on an external storage volume without the need for the access all files permission.

Please update your app so that the feature uses Media Store APIs and remove All Files Access (MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) permission.

Policy: All Files Access Permission

Files and directory attributes on a user's device are regarded as personal and sensitive user data subject to the Personal and Sensitive Information policy and the following requirements:

Apps should only request access to device storage which is critical for the app to function, and may not request access to device storage on behalf of any third-party for any purpose that is unrelated to critical user-facing app functionality.
Android devices running Android "R" (Android 11) or later, will require the MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission in order to manage access in shared storage. All apps that target R or later and request broad access to shared storage ("All files access") must successfully pass an appropriate access review prior to publishing. Apps allowed to use this permission must clearly prompt users to enable "All files access" for their app under "Special app access" settings. For more information on the R requirements, please see this help article.

Read more about Use of All Files Access Permission
See Android storage use cases and best practices and how to access media files from shared storage
Address this issue in the Play Console.

Comment: This is not a question

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.